# How to make my second progress bar work according to the my if statements?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer, progress-bar

I have two progress bars, one is synced with my timer and the second is supposed to run for individual time periods within the total time. Meaning, if the total time is 8 min then the the 1st progress bar runs for the 8 min. The second is supposed to run according to the following if statements:

```
   private void startTimer()
    {
        millisInFuture = mTimeLeftInMillis;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
                long millisPassed = millisInFuture - mTimeLeftInMillis;
                progress = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / millisInFuture);
                pb.setProgress(progress);

                pb2.setProgress(0);
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
/////////////
                    //Key: 60 sec
            if(millisInFuture == 480000) {
                if (millisPassed <= 60000) {
                    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                    stepupimage.setAnimation(animation);
                    progress2 = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / 60000);
                    pb2.setProgress(progress2);
                    if(millisPassed == 60000)
                    {
                        pb2.setProgress(0);
                    }
                } else if (millisPassed > 60000 && millisPassed <= 180000) {
                    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                    stepdownimage.setAnimation(animation);
                    progress2 = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / 120000);
                    pb2.setProgress(progress2);
```

the part of the code that is separated by the backslashes is the one with the problem. the large if statements represents the 8 minutes. The first if statment within it represents the first 1 min of the 8 min. I want the else if statement following it to restart my second progressbar and run it for 2 minutes. Then afterwards, it will restart and run for 1 minute, then restart again and run for 1 minute and so on until the 8 minutes are finished.

I believe the problem is with the value of ***millisPassed*** in the else if statement, but I don't know what to replace it with to make the progress bar restart and run for 2 minutes.

Note:

- pb is the 1st progressbar
- pb2 is the 2nd progressbar